# Prevent Unattented-upgrades from sending reboot notifications to shell

Tags: ubuntu, unattended-upgrades, wall

I am using `Ubuntu 16.04` and have enabled automatic updates and reboots. Version of `unattended-upgrades` is `0.90ubuntu0.9`.

When there is pending reboot and I am logged in to the server I keep getting these notifications to my session:

```
Broadcast message from root@server (Fri 2018-04-06 10:30:00 EEST):
The system is going down for reboot at Sat 2018-04-07 03:30:00 EEST!

Broadcast message from root@server (Fri 2018-04-06 11:30:00 EEST):
The system is going down for reboot at Sat 2018-04-07 03:30:00 EEST!

Broadcast message from root@server (Fri 2018-04-06 12:30:00 EEST):
The system is going down for reboot at Sat 2018-04-07 03:30:00 EEST!

Broadcast message from root@server (Fri 2018-04-06 13:30:00 EEST):
The system is going down for reboot at Sat 2018-04-07 03:30:00 EEST!

Broadcast message from root@server (Fri 2018-04-06 14:30:00 EEST):
The system is going down for reboot at Sat 2018-04-07 03:30:00 EEST!
```

Can I prevent these messages from being sent to shell as it is annoying to receice them and the users know that the server may reboot during maintenance window? I checked `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` but I found only email notification settings there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s no configuration option to do this, but you can disable the broadcast messages by editing the `unattended-upgrade` script (in `/usr/bin`) to pass `--no-wall` to `shutdown`. Look for a line containing

```
subprocess.call(["/sbin/shutdown", "-r", when])
```

and replace that with

```
subprocess.call(["/sbin/shutdown", "-r", when, "--no-wall"])
```

You’ll need to do this every time the `unattended-upgrades` package is upgraded...

(Note that because the shutdown messages are sent by `root`, they can’t be ignored with `mesg n`.)